# postgresql: how to get the last record even with WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql

I have the following postgresql command

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM tablename
   ORDER by id DESC
   LIMIT 1000
) as t
WHERE t.col1="someval"
```

Now i also want to get the last record of along with the above query

```
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM tablename
   ORDER by id DESC
   LIMIT 1000
)
```

Currently i am doing

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM tablename
   ORDER by id DESC
   LIMIT 1000
) as t
WHERE t.col1="someval"

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM tablename
   ORDER by id DESC
   LIMIT 1000
) as t
ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Is this is the right way

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Comment: i just need along with the where clause the last record without where

Answer (score 0):

I would use `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL` in this case, since the final row could also be returned by the first query, and I wouldn't want to have it twice in the result set if that happens. The primary key will guarantee that `UNION` can accidentally remove duplicate result rows.

I don't understand the query, in particular why there is a `WHERE` condition at the outside query in the first case, but not in the second. But that is unrelated to the question.

Comment: I want to select irrespective of where the last row

Comment: I see. But why is the `WHERE` clause outside the `LIMIT 1000`?

Answer (score 0):

Your current effort is wrong, since the LIMIT 1 applies outside the UNION ALL, so you get only one row as a result.  That this is wrong should have been immediately obvious upon testing, so it is baffling that you are asking us if it is right.

You should wrap the whole second SELECT in parenthesis, so the LIMIT applies just to it.

Better yet, rather than ordering and taking 1000 rows and then reversing the order and taking the first row, you could just do `OFFSET 999 LIMIT 1` to get the 1000th row.

If the 1000th rows matches both conditions, do you want to see it twice?